# Is there any reason to use latest version of JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

The [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_OnLoad)

> In order to use any of the new JNI functions, a native library must export a JNI_OnLoad function that returns JNI_VERSION_1_2. If the native library does not export a JNI_OnLoad function, the VM assumes that the library only requires JNI version JNI_VERSION_1_1. If the VM does not recognize the version number returned by JNI_OnLoad, the native library cannot be loaded.

Then, if I don't define the `JNI_OnLoad` function, the version used will be the `JNI_VERSION_1_1`.

So my question is, let's say I'm using java 8, will I encounter any degradation or get into some "compatibility mode" if I don't specify the `JNI_OnLoad` hence using the version `JNI_VERSION_1_1` instead of `JNI_VERSION_1_6` ?

Or in another terms: Is there any gain to specify that I want to work with the latest version even if I don't use the latest added methods ?